# INNER JOIN UPDATE hanging on sending data

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

Trying to update one table from a column in another table based on two conditions. I've tried many version of this but this is what I'm currently trying and it just hangs. When I check the table while running, I'm not seeing any updating occurring. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Thanks!

```
UPDATE earningsdates e
INNER JOIN actualmove a 
ON e.ticker = a.theticker AND e.exactearningsdate = a.realearningsdate
SET e.theamove = a.themove;
```

Comment: The syntax is correct. I think that the tables are huge, and there is no suitable indices in them for this query improvement. PS. Does this condition provides not more than one row in `a` table for each row in `e` table?

Comment: Just got it. I turned ticker and theticker into indexes and the query finished in about 20 seconds. Whew. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made ticker and theticker non-unique indexes and the query worked without a problem.